# Keep track of number of connected clients in expressjs across multi server cluster

Tags: express, redis, server-sent-events

I'm using SSE and need to keep track of the number of active connections across the cluster. In each instance I can do

```
server.getConnections(function(err, count){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(count);
});
```

What would be the best way to keep an accurate total in a cluster with this method and using Redis?

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing all the details of your setup, I would approach this as follows:

- Assuming all your cluster instances talk to the same Redis instance, set up a key called *connection_count* on the Redis store: `SET connection_count 0`.
- Handle the `server.on('connection', (socket) => {...})` method on each cluster node. Inside the handler, atomically increment the value of the *connection_count* key on the Redis store: `INCR connection_count`.
- Handle the `request.on('close', () => {...})` and atomically decrease the *connection_count* value on the Redis store from within the event handler: `DECR connection_count`.